# How do I use a scalar variable in a perl file test operator?

Tags: perl

I am in my first afternoon of perl and am having trouble figuring out what is going wrong with my script. It seems I am not using the file test operator properly, but I am not sure how I am using it incorrectly.

```
use v5.14;

print "what file would you like to find? ";
my $file = <STDIN>;
my $test = -e $file;
if ($test) {
print "File found";
}
else {
print "File not found";
}
```

I have also tried replacing lines 5 and 6 with just

```
if (-e $file) {
```

and line 6 with

```
if ($test == 1) {
```

with no luck.

Comment: The bug is that you forgot to `use warnings`;

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper $file;` The Data::Dumper module is a very useful debugging tool.

Comment: thanks for the tip, much more useful than the 'print $file' I was inserting between lines

Comment: @SherifAnchor You're welcome. `print "'$file'"` might have told you something. But it is simpler to just type `print Dumper $file` IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't the test, it's the contents of `$file`. The end-of-line is not stripped when you do `$file = <STDIN>;`, and chances are you don't have a file with an end-of-line in its filename.

```
chomp($file);
```

after reading it and you should be good to go.

Comment: Or do it all at once.   `chomp (my $file = <STDIN>);`

Answer (score 1):

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html

```
use v5.14;

use warnings;
use strict;

print "what file would you like to find? ";
#chomp to remove new line
chomp my($filename = <STDIN>);

#test if exists but can still be an empty file
if (-e $filename) {
    print "File found\n";
} else {
        print "File not found\n";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile. ① No type `chomp` exists (see the `my [TYPE] VAR` syntax). ② You chomp the `$filename` before it is assigned or even declared. ③ You `use 5.014` but forget the wonderful `say` function. ⇒ `chomp(my $filename = <STDIN>);` … `say "File found"`, `say "File not found"`.

Comment: Fixed thanks! Using say is a choice doesn't mean you have to.